# Invoke another player when one media response(audio playing) is done

Tags: action, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a problem.

I pick up a dialogflow, google action sample (playing a audio file)

I want to build for several audio files.

So when media response is done, media status is invoked.

So at that time, I want to play next audio automatically.

Please help me. I need your kind help.

Thanks.

This is my code.

```
'use strict';

const {
  dialogflow,
  SimpleResponse,
  Image,
  Suggestions,
  MediaObject,
} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

app.intent('Media Response', (conv) => {
  if (!conv.surface.capabilities
    .has('actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO')) {
      conv.ask('Sorry, this device does not support audio playback.');
      conv.ask('Which response would you like to see next?');
      return;
  }

  conv.ask('This is a media response example.');
  conv.ask(new MediaObject({
    name: 'Jazz in Paris',
    url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3',
    description: 'A funky Jazz tune',
    icon: new Image({
      url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/album_art.jpg',
      alt: 'Album cover of an ocean view',
    }),
  }));

  conv.ask(new Suggestions(['cancel']));
});

app.intent('Media Status', (conv) => {
  const mediaStatus = conv.arguments.get('MEDIA_STATUS');
  let response = 'Unknown media status received.';
  if (mediaStatus && mediaStatus.status === 'FINISHED') {
    response = 'Hope you enjoyed the tune! ';
  }
  conv.ask(response);
  conv.ask('Media ended successfully');
  conv.ask(new Suggestions(['exit']));
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I tried to invoke another response on 'Media Status' intent.

```
app.intent('Media Status', (conv) => {
      const mediaStatus = conv.arguments.get('MEDIA_STATUS');
      let response = 'Unknown media status received.';
      if (mediaStatus && mediaStatus.status === 'FINISHED') {
        conv.ask(new MediaObject({
        name: 'Jazz in Paris',
        url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3',
        description: 'A funky Jazz tune',
        icon: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/album_art.jpg',
          alt: 'Album cover of an ocean view',
        }),
      }));

      conv.ask(new Suggestions(['cancel']));
    });
      }

    });
```

Then "Webhook failed for intent: Media Status" error happend. How should I solve this problem? Thank you.

[image: Error]

Comment: I think this addresses your issues, but if not, please update the question with the *text* contents of the `Request`, `Response`, `Debug`, and `Errors` tabs in the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

All responses that include a `MediaObject` must also include a `SimpleResponse` - which is usually just some text that is said before the Media.

For example, in the "Media Response" Intent Handler when you send your first `MediaObject`, you have the line:

```
conv.ask('This is a media response example.');
```

But this sort of line is missing from the "Media Status" Intent Handler.

Comment: Thank you. I found solution, example from medium. I appreciate your kind reply. Thank you again.

Comment: Can you link to the medium article or post your own answer here to explain what worked that you didn't know before?

Comment: See this. https://medium.com/@leonnicholls/if-you-click-on-this-link-you-will-get-a-dialogflow-agent-with-the-fulfillment-code-to-handle-the-b395125ada11